# RGBD-slam for non-ROS fails

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, rgbd6dslam, rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi there,

i tried to use rgbd-slam_freiburg with kinect on ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. i tried with the non-ros-instruction from [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam#RGB-D_SLAM_for_Non-ROS_Users).

it fails at **rosmake rgbdslam_freiburg** by compiling the rgbdslam stack. here is my output:

> st-admin@ubuntu:~$ rosmake
> rgbdslam_freiburg  [ rosmake ] rosmake
> starting...
> [ rosmake ] Packages requested are:
> ['rgbdslam_freiburg']
> [ rosmake ] Logging to directory
> /home/st-admin/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130115-131451
> [ rosmake ] Expanded args
> ['rgbdslam_freiburg'] to: ['rgbdslam']
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [
> make ]
> [rosmake-1] Starting >>> geometry_msgs
> [ make ]
> [rosmake-2] Starting >>> opencv2 [
> make ]
> [rosmake-2] Finished <<< opencv2
> ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2
> [rosmake-2] Starting >>> bullet [ make
> ]
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No
> Makefile in package roslang
> [rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosconsole [
> make ]
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make
> ]
> [rosmake-1] Finished <<< geometry_msgs
> No Makefile in package geometry_msgs
> [rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp [ make
> ]
> [rosmake-2] Finished <<< bullet
> ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet
> [rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosconsole
> No Makefile in package rosconsole
> [rosmake-2] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [
> make ]
> [rosmake-3] Starting >>> angles [ make
> ]
> [rosmake-3] Finished <<< angles
> ROS_NOBUILD in package angles
> [rosmake-3] Starting >>> rostest [
> make ]
> [rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp  No
> Makefile in package roscpp
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy  No
> Makefile in package rospy
> [rosmake-1] Starting >>> roswtf [ make
> ]
> [rosmake-2] Finished <<< sensor_msgs
> No Makefile in package sensor_msgs
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>>
> message_filters [ make ]
> [rosmake-3] Finished <<< rostest  No
> Makefile in package rostest
> [rosmake-3] Starting >>> std_msgs [
> make ]
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<<
> message_filters  No Makefile in
> package message_filters [rosmake-2]
> Starting >>> image_geometry [ make ]
> [rosmake-2] Finished <<<
> image_geometry ROS_NOBUILD in package
> image_geometry    [rosmake-0] Starting
>
> > > > rosbag [ make ]                                         [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosbuild [
> > > > make ]
> > > > [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosbuild  No
> > > > Makefile in package rosbuild
> > > > [rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslib [ make
> > > > ]
> > > > [rosmake-3] Finished <<< std_msgs  No
> > > > Makefile in package std_msgs
> > > > [rosmake-3] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]
> > > > [rosmake-1] Finished <<< roswtf  No
> > > > Makefile in package roswtf
> > > > [rosmake-1] Starting >>> tf [ make ]
> > > > [rosmake-1] Finished <<< tf
> > > > ROS_NOBUILD in package tf
> > > > [rosmake-1] Starting >>> smclib [ make
> > > > ]
> > > > [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag  No
> > > > Makefile in package rosbag
> > > > [rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslib  No
> > > > Makefile in package roslib
> > > > [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosservice [
> > > > make ]
> > > > [rosmake-3] Finished <<< pcl
> > > > ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl  No
> > > > Makefile in package pcl [rosmake-2]
> > > > Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]
> > > > [rosmake-1] Finished <<< smclib
> > > > ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib
> > > > [rosmake-3] Starting >>> bond [ make ]
> > > > [rosmake-1] Starting >>>
> > > > common_rosdeps [ make ]
> > > > [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosservice
> > > > No Makefile in package rosservice
> > > > [rosmake-3] Finished <<< bond
> > > > ROS_NOBUILD in package bond
> > > > [rosmake-2] Finished <<< pluginlib
> > > > ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib
> > > > [rosmake-0] Starting >>>
> > > > dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]
> > > > [rosmake-3] Starting >>> bondcpp [
> > > > make ]
> > > > [rosmake-1] Finished <<<
> > > > common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package
> > > > common_rosdeps    [rosmake-2] Starting
> > > > cv_bridge [ make ]                                      [rosmake-2] Finished <<< cv_bridge
> > > > ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge
> > > > [rosmake-1] Starting >>>
> > > > visualization_msgs [ make ]
> > > > [rosmake-2] Starting >>> mk [ make ]
> > > > [rosmake-2] Finished <<< mk  No
> > > > Makefile in package mk
> > > > [rosmake-2] Starting >>> orocos_kdl [
> > > > make ]
> > > > [rosmake-1] Finished <<<
> > > > visualization_msgs  No Makefile in
> > > > package visualization_msgs [rosmake-0]
> > > > Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure
> > > > ROS_NOBUILD in package
> > > > dynamic_reconfigure [rosmake-1]
> > > > Starting >>> opencv_tests [ make ]
> > > > [rosmake-1] Finished <<< opencv_tests
> > > > ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv_tests
> > > > [rosmake-3] Finished <<< bondcpp
> > > > ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp
> > > > [rosmake-3] Starting >>> nodelet [
> > > > make ]
> > > > [rosmake-2] Finished <<< orocos_kdl
> > > > ROS_NOBUILD in package orocos_kdl
> > > > [rosmake-2] Starting >>>
> > > > python_orocos_kdl [ make ]
> > > > [rosmake-3] Finished <<< nodelet
> > > > ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet
> > > > [rosmake-3] Starting >>>
> > > > nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]
> > > > [rosmake-2] Finished <<<
> > > > python_orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in
> > > > package python_orocos_kdl [rosmake-2]
> > > > Starting >>> kdl [ make ]
> > > > [rosmake-3] Finished <<<
> > > > nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in
> > > > package nodelet_topic_tools
> > > > [rosmake-3] Starting >>> pcl_ros [
> > > > make ]
> > > > [rosmake-3] Finished <<< pcl_ros
> > > > ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros
> > > > [rosmake-3] Starting >>> rgbdslam [
> > > > make ]
> > > > [rosmake-2] Finished <<< kdl
> > > > ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl  No
> > > > Makefile in package kdl [rosmake-2]
> > > > Starting >>> eigen_conversions [ make
> > > > ]
> > > > [rosmake-1] Starting >>>
> > > > tf_conversions [ make ]
> > > > [rosmake-1] Finished <<<
> > > > tf_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package
> > > > tf_conversions    [rosmake-2] Finished
> > > > <<< eigen_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in
> > > > package eigen_conversions [rosmake-1]
> > > > Starting >>> cv_markers [ make ]
> > > > [rosmake-1] Finished <<< cv_markers
> > > > ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_markers
> > > > [ rosmake ] Last 40 linesbdslam: 10.6
> > > > sec ]          [ 1 Active 39/40
> > > > Complete ]
> > > > {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------   make[3]: Nothing to be done for
> > > > `targets'.   make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/test'
> > > > make[2]: Leaving directory
> > > > `/home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/test' cd sample ; make linux-g++   make[2]: Entering directory` /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/sample'
> > > > make targets \    "ANNLIB = libANN.a"
> > > > \     "C++ = g++" \       "CFLAGS = -O3" 
> > > > "MAKELIB = ar ruv" \    "RANLIB =
> > > > true"   make[3]: Entering directory
> > > > `/home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/sample' make[3]: Nothing to be done for` targets'.   make[3]: Leaving
> > > > directory
> > > > `/home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/sample' make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/sample'
> > > > cd ann2fig ; make linux-g++   make[2]:
> > > > Entering directory
> > > > `/home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/ann2fig' make targets \    "ANNLIB = libANN.a" \     "C++ = g++" \       "CFLAGS = -O3" \ "MAKELIB = ar ruv" \    "RANLIB = true"   make[3]: Entering directory` /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/ann2fig'
> > > > make[3]: Nothing to be done for
> > > > `targets'.   make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/ann2fig'
> > > > make[2]: Leaving directory
> > > > `/home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/ann2fig' make[1]: Leaving directory` /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2'
> > > > ------------------------------------------------------------------
> > > > -- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)   [rosbuild]
> > > > Couldn't find source file
> > > > /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_qtros.cxx;
> > > > assuming that it is in
> > > > /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam
> > > > and will be generated later
> > > > [rosbuild] Couldn't find source file
> > > > /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_openni_listener.cxx;
> > > > assuming that it is in
> > > > /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam
> > > > and will be generated later
> > > > [rosbuild] Couldn't find source file
> > > > /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_qt_gui.cxx;
> > > > assuming that it is in
> > > > /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam
> > > > and will be generated later
> > > > [rosbuild] Couldn't find source file
> > > > /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_graph_manager.cxx;
> > > > assuming that it is in
> > > > /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam
> > > > and will be generated later
> > > > [rosbuild] Couldn't find source file
> > > > /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_glviewer.cxx;
> > > > assuming that it is in
> > > > /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam
> > > > and will be generated later
> > > > [rosbuild] Couldn't find source file
> > > > /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_ros_service_ui.cxx;
> > > > assuming that it is in
> > > > /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam
> > > > and will be generated later   --
> > > > Configuring incomplete, errors
> > > > occurred!
> > > > -------------------------------------------------------------------------------} [ rosmake ] Output from build of
> > > > package rgbdslam written to: [ rosmake
> > > > ]
> > > > /home/st-admin/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130115-131451/rgbdslam/build_output.log
> > > > [rosmake-3] Finished <<< rgbdslam
> > > > [FAIL] [ 10.72 seconds ]
> > > > [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in
> > > > package rgbdslam.  [ rosmake ] Waiting
> > > > for other threads to complete. [
> > > > rosmake ] Results:
> > > > [ rosmake ] Built 40 packages with 1
> > > > failures.
> > > > [ rosmake ] Summary output to
> > > > directory
> > > > [ rosmake ]
> > > > /home/st-admin/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130115-131451

for me it seems that there are data missing from the rgbd itself?!

any ideas?

**edit**

here the log from rosmake (/home/st-admin/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130115-131451/rgbdslam/build_output.log):

> mkdir -p bin cd build && cmake -Wdev
> -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
> [rosbuild] Building package rgbdslam
> [rosbuild] Including
> /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
> [rosbuild] Including
> /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
> [rosbuild] Including
> /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:57
> (find_package):   Could not find
> module Findg2o.cmake or a
> configuration file for package   g2o.
>
> Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find
> Findg2o.cmake or set g2o_DIR to the
> directory containing a CMake
> configuration file for g2o.  The file
> will   have one of the following
> names:
>
> ```
> g2oConfig.cmake
> g2o-config.cmake
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Compiling SiftGPU... make[1]: Entering
> directory
> `/home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/siftgpu/linux' mkdir -p ../../../build/siftgpu mkdir -p ./bin  ln ../data/ -d -s -f ar rcs ./bin/libsiftgpu.a ../../../build/siftgpu/FrameBufferObject.o ../../../build/siftgpu/GlobalUtil.o ../../../build/siftgpu/GLTexImage.o ../../../build/siftgpu/ProgramGLSL.o ../../../build/siftgpu/ProgramGPU.o ../../../build/siftgpu/ShaderMan.o ../../../build/siftgpu/SiftGPU.o ../../../build/siftgpu/SiftPyramid.o ../../../build/siftgpu/PyramidGL.o ../../../build/siftgpu/SiftMatch.o g++ -o ./bin/libsiftgpu.so ../../../build/siftgpu/FrameBufferObject.o ../../../build/siftgpu/GlobalUtil.o ../../../build/siftgpu/GLTexImage.o ../../../build/siftgpu/ProgramGLSL.o ../../../build/siftgpu/ProgramGPU.o ../../../build/siftgpu/ShaderMan.o ../../../build/siftgpu/SiftGPU.o ../../../build/siftgpu/SiftPyramid.o ../../../build/siftgpu/PyramidGL.o ../../../build/siftgpu/SiftMatch.o -lGLEW -lglut -lIL -lGL -lX11 -I../include -fPIC -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib -L./bin -Wall -Wno-deprecated -pthread   -march=native -mfpmath=sse -shared -fPIC make[1]: Leaving directory` /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/siftgpu/linux'
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> Compiling GICP... make[1]: Entering
> directory
> `/home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2' cd src ; make linux-g++ make[2]: Entering directory` /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/src'
> make targets \    "ANNLIB = libANN.a" 
> "C++ = g++" \   "CFLAGS = -O3" 
> "MAKELIB = ar ruv" \    "RANLIB = true"
> make[3]: Entering directory
> `/home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/src' make[3]: Nothing to be done for` targets'. make[3]: Leaving directory
> `/home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/src' make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/src'
> cd test ; make linux-g++ make[2]:
> Entering directory
> `/home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/test' make targets \    "ANNLIB = libANN.a" \ "C++ = g++" \   "CFLAGS = -O3" \ "MAKELIB = ar ruv" \    "RANLIB = true" make[3]: Entering directory` /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/test'
> make[3]: Nothing to be done for
> `targets'. make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/test'
> make[2]: Leaving directory
> `/home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/test' cd sample ; make linux-g++ make[2]: Entering directory` /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/sample'
> make targets \    "ANNLIB = libANN.a" 
> "C++ = g++" \   "CFLAGS = -O3" 
> "MAKELIB = ar ruv" \    "RANLIB = true"
> make[3]: Entering directory
> `/home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/sample' make[3]: Nothing to be done for` targets'. make[3]: Leaving directory
> `/home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/sample' make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/sample'
> cd ann2fig ; make linux-g++ make[2]:
> Entering directory
> `/home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/ann2fig' make targets \    "ANNLIB = libANN.a" \ "C++ = g++" \   "CFLAGS = -O3" \ "MAKELIB = ar ruv" \    "RANLIB = true" make[3]: Entering directory` /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/ann2fig'
> make[3]: Nothing to be done for
> `targets'. make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/ann2fig'
> make[2]: Leaving directory
> `/home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/ann2fig' make[1]: Leaving directory` /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2'
>
> ---
>
> -- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3) [rosbuild]
> Couldn't find source file
> /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_qtros.cxx;
> assuming that it is in
> /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam
> and will be generated later [rosbuild]
> Couldn't find source file
> /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_openni_listener.cxx;
> assuming that it is in
> /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam
> and will be generated later [rosbuild]
> Couldn't find source file
> /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_qt_gui.cxx;
> assuming that it is in
> /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam
> and will be generated later [rosbuild]
> Couldn't find source file
> /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_graph_manager.cxx;
> assuming that it is in
> /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam
> and will be generated later [rosbuild]
> Couldn't find source file
> /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_glviewer.cxx;
> assuming that it is in
> /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam
> and will be generated later [rosbuild]
> Couldn't find source file
> /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_ros_service_ui.cxx;
> assuming that it is in
> /home/st-admin/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam
> and will be generated later
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! make: *** [all] Error 1

**edit 2**

after trying to install libg2o it seems that it is already installed.

> st-admin@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get
> install ros-fuerte-libg2o Reading
> package lists... Done Building
> dependency tree        Reading state
> information... Done ros-fuerte-libg2o
> is already the newest version. 0
> upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to
> remove and 0 not upgraded.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52223/rgbd-slam-for-non-ros-fails/) by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-01-15**:
"Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!" is the problem. However, your post doesn't include the output of the configuration, which would typically be above the excerpt you posted

**Comment by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on 2013-01-15**:
@Felix Endres: now i added the whole outpost from make, do you need any more informations? for me it seems that there are data missing from the rgbd itself?  Couldn't find source file .../mydir/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_qtros.cxx and so on.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-01-15**:
No, those are not errors. Those files really will be generated later. You need to post this build log: /home/st-admin/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130115-131451/rgbdslam/build_output.log [rosmake-3] or just the raw output of `make` (not rosmake).

**Comment by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on 2013-01-15**:
@dornhege: thanks for the hint! i added the log to the original post.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-01-15**:
Seems to be g2o missing. Try `sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-libg2o`. I think that might do it.

**Comment by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on 2013-01-15**:
thanks, but it does not solve the problem. seems that g2o is already installed, check my original post ;)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-01-15**:
This seems to pertain to g2o under fuerte: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam#Installation_with_Fuerte Maybe that helps.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-01-27**:
Does it work now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just applied the patch from http://answers.ros.org/question/51013/rgbdslam-fixed-for-fuerte-where-do-i-send-the-patch/ to the repository. Try updating and rebuilding, it should find g2o.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0